# What will happen if I begin a war for independence without colonies adjacent to the sea?

Tags: colonization

In the old Colonization, where will the troops drop during a war for independence when I have no coastal colonies?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't a screenshot provided so I can't pin-point an exact location for you. Troops will usually drop on either your northern or southern coast. Since you have no coastal territories the troops will come by your nothern province or your southern province.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter V says, you get attacked overland.  The most effective tactic I found was to have **exactly** two coastal colonies.  Full fortification, a bazillion cannons and some troops.  The redcoats come and smash themselves against your defenses.

The redcoats land in two locations so you have to provide two cities for them to attack if you want to control them.  Having more than two just means you have defenses that won't be used.